# How should I plot a multi-split (non binary split) decision tree run from RWeka J48() function?

Tags: r, plot, tree, visualization, rweka

I try to build a multi-split tree with the option of J48() function:

`mytree = J48(class ~ ., data=train.set,  na.action = NULL, control= Weka_control(U=TRUE, B=FALSE))`

and it seems to work fine. But I cannot plot the decision tree by any of the following codes:

`if(require("partykit", quietly = TRUE)) plot(mytree)`

by using the plot tool in the partykit package. The manual says it only plots the binary-split tree.
Or the code:

`prp(mytree)`

by using the plot function in the rpart.plot package. Because R shows the warning message

`Error in prp(mytree) : Not an rpart object`

Can anyone tell me how to plot this tree?

Comment: Since you do not provide your data, it is very difficult to help you. I was able to construct a non-binary tree using J48 and plot it. Please type `dput(mytree)` and paste the results into your question so that we can try to figure out why your tree is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

The data I use is the heart disease data from UCI repository, and it looks like
`> head(Hungarian)`


      `age sex cp trestbps chol fbs restecg thalach exang oldpeak slope ca thal num
    1  28   1  2      130  132   0       2     185     0       0  <NA> NA <NA>   0
    2  29   1  2      120  243   0       0     160     0       0  <NA> NA <NA>   0
    3  29   1  2      140   NA   0       0     170     0       0  <NA> NA <NA>   0
    4  30   0  1      170  237   0       1     170     0       0  <NA> NA    6   0
    5  31   0  2      100  219   0       1     150     0       0  <NA> NA <NA>   0
    6  32   0  2      105  198   0       0     165     0       0  <NA> NA <NA>   0`

The class variable is the variable num (0 or 1). And the result of typing `dput(mytree)` 
is

```
structure(list(classifier = new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x0de0e848>, 
jclass = "java/lang/Object"), predictions = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), call = J48(formula = num ~ ., data = train.set, 
    na.action = NULL, control = Weka_control(U = TRUE, B = FALSE)), 
    handlers = list(data = function (mf) 
    {
        terms <- attr(mf, "terms")
        if (any(attr(terms, "order") > 1L)) 
            stop("Interactions are not allowed.")
        factors <- attr(terms, "factors")
        varnms <- rownames(factors)[c(TRUE, rowSums(factors)[-1L] > 
            0)]
        mf[, sub("^`(.*)`$", "\\1", varnms), drop = FALSE]
    }), levels = c("0", "1"), terms = num ~ age + sex + cp + 
        trestbps + chol + fbs + restecg + thalach + exang + oldpeak + 
        slope + ca + thal), class = c("J48", "Weka_tree", "Weka_classifier"
))
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After re-running the process, the code

```
 prp(mytree)
```

doesn't work with the warning message

```
 Error in prp(mytree) : Not an rpart object
```

However, the following code works

```
 plot(as.party.Weka_tree(mytree))
```

referring 
[How do you plot a CostSensitiveClassifier tree in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420191/how-do-you-plot-a-costsensitiveclassifier-tree-in-r)

Is there anyone who knows the reason?